# Stop bots without captcha - with a twist

Tags: php, mysql, html, macros, bots

This is different to the other questions on this topic. I'll try to make this relevant to as many people as I can, though it is a fairly specific problem.

Imagine a button(html button) on a website that, after it has been clicked a certain number of times, will give the user a 'point'. The points are stored in a database for many users and these points can be transferred between accounts. 
I don't want someone to just make a quick macro to keep clicking the button while they sleep and so I need some sort of solution. Here's the options that I think have some potential:

1. Use a recaptcha for every single time they want to click the button (painful).
2. Use cookies and recaptcha so it allows them 10 clicks (say), but then asks for recaptcha verification. (they could just delete the cookie).
3. Use an alternative to captcha that isn't too painful.

And other 'iffy' ideas:
-Simply moving the button around the page in combination with some other sneaky strategy.
-When the user presses the button they are required to submit some sort of puzzle which will be used to check if others are human.

What do you think?
Also, is it at all possible to have the points system almost 100% unhackable/unmacroable? It's very important that the system is secure. Any potential problems you can with such an idea?

Thanks.

Comment: I suppose you could count the number of clicks per second for every user. Average it in the database, and if a user goes decently above that, then prompt them for captcha.  You'd need to be careful though, if every user used a macro, then the average clicks per second would be artificially high

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than a button, make a clickable image with a target. Make the image dynamic and the target be something specified elsewhere on the page (maybe just above the image). So, for instance, one time it could be "Click on the square" with a square and a triangle showing in the image. The next time it might be "Click outside the circle" with a circle in the lower half of the image. The possibilities are endless. (I'd stay away from using color as the only clue, out of consideration for the color-blind.) Any bot would have to know what coordinates to send back to simulate the mouse clicking in the correct target area.

Comment: This is interesting. Sounds fairly full-proof. Does this requires a lot of image making and mapping? What is the neatest way to implement this do you think?

Comment: @user1104147 - I would look at using an image library to generate the images procedurally. It wouldn't take too many rules, I think, to define a fairly large set of images. The same rules could be the basis for selecting the targets and hints.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's impossible to make any system 100% unmacroable. That said, you can make it mighty tough for the user to "macro" it.

You can use a combination of solutions for this.

a) You can set up a hidden form field with `""` value, which you'll check on submit to see the value. Bots usually go in by filling each form field with data, and this'll ward these ones off.

b) You can use a javascript to check to see that the mouse was actually clicked.

c) (I don't know if this is possible) but you can check to see if the mouse has been moved at all for the last X seconds. Any human being (hopefully) will use their mouse even a little bit every few seconds.

d) Add a captcha every X clicks.

And more stuff like this.

Comment: Your points b) and c) would require JS to be turned on (which if it's a bot, it generally won't be). The other 2 points would be a good idea to use.

Comment: True, but you can have the javascript just create another hidden `input` field and on submit, the script can check the existence and correctness of the field. (I seem to be a big fan of hidden input fields! :P )

Comment: It sounds like the OP is worried about people custom-scripting bots specifically for his button. a) doesn't really apply in that case.

Comment: @Indranil but if you do that then the form just won't work to those people who don't have JS enabled (it's a bigger percentage of people than you would think...). I guess it really depends on the OP's requirements, if they are okay with it not working for non-js users or not :)

Comment: @Nick that is very true. All of it, of course, depends on the requirements.

Comment: Yes I am looking to deter custom bots, so a) is out, but I love b) and c), thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd set it up to:

1. After 10 consecutive clicks in the same session make the user input
   some kind of math check (i.e. generate 2 random numbers, make the
   user add/subtract them together and type the answer into an input
   box).
2. Every 20 clicks ask for a captcha to be filled out.
3. Reset the counter. This allows the system to always give them some
   kind of check every 10 consecutive clicks.

An unobtrusive system is pretty hard to create.

Other than that you could:

- Only allow a certain amount of clicks per minute
- Store average clicks/minute against each user in the database so you can take a look and disqualify/remove points from users who are abusing the system.